# Why did Charlie end up on the penal planet?

Tags: nights-dawn-trilogy

In the closing chapter of *The Naked God*, we find André Duchamp greeted upon landing by a young man introducing himself as Charles Montgomery David Filton-Asquith, who we know as Charlie of B7. My first thought was that Charlie had sent his retired clone self to the penal planet instead of killing him off, but Hamilton explicitly calls him a young man, ruling this out.

Why would Charlie leave Earth for a penal planet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussion [here](http://www.theunisphere.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=17) (search for Charlie on the page), 
The B7 were punished for the various crimes they committed while ruling Earth and sent to the penal colony by Joshua when he was in god mode.